# multiple listeners in table tr, description mentioned has html comment

Tags: javascript, html

> In the below code, am adding a new each employee on a table tr,
> where on each tr am adding a button called edit and attaching a listener,
> where one can edit the emp details, My prblm is first on editing a specific row it is working fine,
> but on second and successive clicks on any particular row submit listener inside edit is called multiple times,

**i have resolved this issue, but want to know why the below code is not working**

```js
    const add = document.getElementById('btn');
            let table = document.getElementById('table');
            let modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
            let id = 0;

            function createPerson() {
                id++;
                const name = prompt('Enter Name');
                const salary = '5';
                const designation = 'eng';

                let row = document.createElement('tr');

                row.innerHTML = `<td>${id}</td>
                <td>${name}</td>
                <td>${salary}</td>
                <td>${designation}</td>
                <td><button>Edit</button></td>
                <td><button>delete</button></td>`;
                table.append(row);

                row.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', editDetails);
            }

            function editDetails(e) {
                const editRow = e.target.parentNode.parentNode;
                modal.classList.toggle('modal');

                function submit() {
                    let name = document.getElementById('name').value;
                    let salary = document.getElementById('salary').value;
                    let designation = document.getElementById('designation').value;

                    editRow.innerHTML = `<td>${id}</td>
    <td>${name}</td>
    <td>${salary}</td>
    <td>${designation}</td>
    <td><button>Edit</button></td>`;

                    modal.classList.toggle('modal');
                }
                document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', submit);
            }

            add.addEventListener('click', createPerson);
```

```css
/*
=============== 
Fonts
===============
*/
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans|Roboto:400,700&display=swap");

/*
=============== 
Variables
===============
*/

:root {
  /* dark shades of primary color*/
  --clr-primary-1: hsl(205, 86%, 17%);
  --clr-primary-2: hsl(205, 77%, 27%);
  --clr-primary-3: hsl(205, 72%, 37%);
  --clr-primary-4: hsl(205, 63%, 48%);
  /* primary/main color */
  --clr-primary-5: hsl(205, 78%, 60%);
  /* lighter shades of primary color */
  --clr-primary-6: hsl(205, 89%, 70%);
  --clr-primary-7: hsl(205, 90%, 76%);
  --clr-primary-8: hsl(205, 86%, 81%);
  --clr-primary-9: hsl(205, 90%, 88%);
  --clr-primary-10: hsl(205, 100%, 96%);
  /* darkest grey - used for headings */
  --clr-grey-1: hsl(209, 61%, 16%);
  --clr-grey-2: hsl(211, 39%, 23%);
  --clr-grey-3: hsl(209, 34%, 30%);
  --clr-grey-4: hsl(209, 28%, 39%);
  /* grey used for paragraphs */
  --clr-grey-5: hsl(210, 22%, 49%);
  --clr-grey-6: hsl(209, 23%, 60%);
  --clr-grey-7: hsl(211, 27%, 70%);
  --clr-grey-8: hsl(210, 31%, 80%);
  --clr-grey-9: hsl(212, 33%, 89%);
  --clr-grey-10: hsl(210, 36%, 96%);
  --clr-white: #fff;
  --clr-red-dark: hsl(360, 67%, 44%);
  --clr-red-light: hsl(360, 71%, 66%);
  --clr-green-dark: hsl(125, 67%, 44%);
  --clr-green-light: hsl(125, 71%, 66%);
  --clr-black: #222;
  --ff-primary: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  --ff-secondary: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  --transition: all 0.3s linear;
  --spacing: 0.1rem;
  --radius: 0.25rem;
  --light-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  --dark-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  --max-width: 1170px;
  --fixed-width: 620px;
}
/*
=============== 
Global Styles
===============
*/

*,
::after,
::before {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  font-family: var(--ff-secondary);
  background: var(--clr-grey-10);
  color: var(--clr-grey-1);
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4 {
  letter-spacing: var(--spacing);
  text-transform: capitalize;
  line-height: 1.25;
  margin-bottom: 0.75rem;
  font-family: var(--ff-primary);
}
h1 {
  font-size: 3rem;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 2rem;
}
h3 {
  font-size: 1.25rem;
}
h4 {
  font-size: 0.875rem;
}
p {
  margin-bottom: 1.25rem;
  color: var(--clr-grey-5);
}
@media screen and (min-width: 800px) {
  h1 {
    font-size: 4rem;
  }
  h2 {
    font-size: 2.5rem;
  }
  h3 {
    font-size: 1.75rem;
  }
  h4 {
    font-size: 1rem;
  }
  body {
    font-size: 1rem;
  }
  h1,
  h2,
  h3,
  h4 {
    line-height: 1;
  }
}
/*  global classes */

/* section */
.section {
  padding: 5rem 0;
}

.section-center {
  width: 90vw;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1170px;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  .section-center {
    width: 95vw;
  }
}
main {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}

/*
=============== 
Nav
===============
*/
nav {
  background: var(--clr-white);
  height: 3rem;
  display: grid;
  align-items: center;
  box-shadow: var(--dark-shadow);
}
.nav-center {
  width: 90vw;
  max-width: var(--fixed-width);
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.nav-center h4 {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  color: var(--clr-primary-5);
}
.nav-links {
  display: flex;
}
nav a {
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: var(--clr-primary-1);
  letter-spacing: var(--spacing);
  margin-right: 1rem;
}
nav a:hover {
  color: var(--clr-primary-5);
}
/*
=============== 
Container
===============
*/
main {
  min-height: calc(100vh - 3rem);
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}
.container {
  text-align: center;
}
.container h2 {
  background: var(--clr-black);
  color: var(--clr-white);
  padding: 1rem;
  border-radius: var(--radius);
  margin-bottom: 2.5rem;
}
.color {
  color: var(--clr-primary-5);
}
.btn-hero {
  font-family: var(--ff-primary);
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background: transparent;
  color: var(--clr-black);
  letter-spacing: var(--spacing);
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: 700;
  transition: var(--transition);
  border: 2px solid var(--clr-black);
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: var(--radius);
  font-size: 1rem;
  padding: 0.75rem 1.25rem;
}
.btn-hero:hover {
  color: var(--clr-white);
  background: var(--clr-black);
}

.show{
    display: block;
}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
  }
  
  /* Modal Content/Box */
  .modal-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: 15% auto; /* 15% from the top and centered */
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 80%; /* Could be more or less, depending on screen size */
  }
  
  /* The Close Button */
  .close {
    color: #aaa;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  
  .close:hover,
  .close:focus {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <!-- In the below code, am adding a new each employee on a table tr, 
        where on each tr am adding a button called edit and attaching a listener, 
        where one can edit the emp details, My prblm is first on editing a specific row it is working fine, 
        but on second and successive clicks on any particular row submit listener inside edit is called multiple times. 
     -->
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Color Flipper || Simple</title>

        <!-- styles -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Employee List</h1>
        <div>
            <div>
                <button id="btn" class="btn-hero">Add New Employee</button>
            </div>
            <div>
                <h4>List</h4>
                <table id="table">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="padding-right: 15px">ID</td>
                        <td style="padding-right: 15px">Name</td>
                        <td style="padding-right: 15px">Salary</td>
                        <td style="padding-right: 15px">designation</td>
                        <td style="padding-right: 15px">Edit</td>
                        <td style="padding-right: 15px">Delete</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <div id="myModal" class="modal">
                    <!-- Modal content -->
                    <div id="modal-content" class="modal-content">
                        <label>Name</label>
                        <input type="text" id="name" class="name" />
                        <label>Salary</label>
                        <input type="text" id="salary" class="salary" />
                        <label>Designation</label>
                        <input type="text" id="designation" class="designation" />
                        <button id="submit">Submit</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script>
        
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you wrote a lot of logic inside the edit handler.
Each time `editDetails` is called, it adds a new event listener on the submit button. This event is actually uses the function submit which is nested in the `editDetails` handler. And due to `closure`, the `editRow` variable is kept in the memory, and its value remains as it is.

On the first click on edit, it adds a new listener to the submit with the clicked row info.
The second time, the previous one is kept and a new one added ... and so on. (This time, a one-click will call 2 methods)

Here is a suggested solution for this:

```
let editRow;
function editDetails(e) {
  editRow = e.target.parentNode.parentNode;
  modal.classList.toggle('modal');
}

document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', submit);

function submit() {
    let name = document.getElementById('name').value;
    let salary = document.getElementById('salary').value;
    let designation = document.getElementById('designation').value;

    editRow.innerHTML = `<td>${id}</td>
<td>${name}</td>
<td>${salary}</td>
<td>${designation}</td>
<td><button>Edit</button></td>`;

    modal.classList.toggle('modal');
}
```

Check [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) for more info about `Closure`.

Comment: i found out the solution already but Still confused coz each time on clicking edit. new submit function is created and added as listener right?

Comment: Yes, that is what happens.

Comment: it is creating a new submit function each time, how much the new submit will hold the previous edit value as closure. u can check in chrome dev tools by placing a breakpoint

Comment: `function editDetails(e) {
  const editRow = e.target.parentNode.parentNode;
  modal.classList.toggle('modal');
  document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', () => submit(editRow));
}


function submit(editRow) {
  let name = document.getElementById('name').value;
  let salary = document.getElementById('salary').value;
  let designation = document.getElementById('designation').value;

  editRow.innerHTML = `<td>${id}</td>
<td>${name}</td>
<td>${salary}</td>
<td>${designation}</td>
<td><button>Edit</button></td>`;

  modal.classList.toggle('modal');
}`

Comment: if closure is the issue here, can u help me out why the above implementation is not working too, even though am passing editRow as an argument to the function

Comment: When a function is implemented inside another function, it keeps all the variables' values in memory.
Since each time `editDetails` creates a new event listener and passes the `submit` function to it, it takes a copy of that function with all its parent function's values. As you know, `addEventListener` keeps adding new handlers and doesn't override the previous ones. So, the second time, it has 2 handlers for the "click" event. One of them has the first row in the `editRow` variable and the second one has the current (second clicked) row. That keeps happening on each click.

Comment: Try to add `console.log(editRow);` at the beginning of the `submit` function, and check the rows in the console.

Comment: The code you added in the comment above is the same. Try to make the `editRow` a global variable and inside the `editDetails` just override it.
`let editRow;
    function editDetails(e) { 
      editRow = e.target.parentNode.parentNode; `
That will solve a part of the issue, and may make it clearer why the closure is the reason for the above codes.

Comment: function editDetails(e) {
  const editRow = e.target.parentNode.parentNode;
  modal.classList.toggle('modal');
  function submit() {
    let name = document.getElementById('name').value;
    let salary = document.getElementById('salary').value;
    editRow.innerHTML = `<td>${id}</td>
    <td>${name}</td>
    <td>${salary}</td>
    <td>${designation}</td>
    <td><button>Edit</button></td>`;
    modal.classList.toggle('modal');
    document.getElementById('submit').removeEventListener('click', submit)
  }
  document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', submit);
}

Comment: I have a resolve the issue by above, where i can remove the listener on every time on executing the submit, i guess more of understanding closure here, 
each time on attaching listener to submit button, and since submit button is only one element, on every editDetails function call listeners **are added instead of overriding**,

Comment: Yes. Removing it each time is a solution, too.